# FB Payments Object is incorrect

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, payment, facebook-payments

I've found strange response of graph.facebook.com for all payment objects of my new app.

If I've sent this URL to graph:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/6XXX9795855XXXXX?access_token=APP|TOKEN
```

with valid paymentId (this ID I received via RealTime Update).

I got this response:

```
{ "created_time": "2015-07-20T07:54:13+0000", "id": "6XX9795855XXXXX" }
```

Could someone explain, why this happens? All Canvas Payments settings are correct.

I've tried to make queries to different API versions (v1.0, v2.0, v2.3, v2.4).

Dashboard section of app settings says, that my app has API 2.4 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, API2.4...

If your app has API 2.4 version, in each query to graph with paymentID you need include all coma-separeted fields, that you want to get.

So, your request

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAYMENT_ID?access_token=APP|SECRET
```

turns into

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAYMENT_ID?access_token=APP|SECRET&fields=id,user,application,actions,refundable_amount,items,country,request_id,created_time,payout_foreign_exchange_rate,tax,tax_country
```

It's works.

Why facebook breaks one of ideal payment responses? Why I should keep-in-memory all data, that I wants to get, and what I should to do, when new payment field (such as tax) will be added to payment object?